# Updating picklist value using metadata api

Tags: apex, metadata-api, picklist

I'm updating picklist value using metadata api and apex. Below is my code snippet and I'm receiving an error:

> Variable does not exists: picklist

on:

```
customField.picklist = pt ;
```

Can someone help me?

```
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
        service.updateMetadata(
            new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });



  MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
    customField.fullName = 'Lead.picklist__c';
    customField.label = 'picklist';
    customField.type_x = 'Picklist';
    metadataservice.Picklist pt = new metadataservice.Picklist();
    pt.sorted= false;
    metadataservice.PicklistValue two = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
    two.fullName= 'second';
    two.default_x=false ;
    metadataservice.PicklistValue three = new metadataservice.PicklistValue();
    three.fullName= 'third';
    three.default_x=false ;
    pt.picklistValues = new list<metadataservice.PicklistValue>{two,three};
    customField.picklist = pt ;
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
        service.updateMetadata(
            new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
```

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217350/how-to-update-picklist-using-rest-api. Using a REST call over the Tooling API is generally the best way to go for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `picklist` on the [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) object is deprecated. You will have to use the `valueSet` field instead.

Here is how the updated code would look like

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Lead.picklist__c';
customField.label = 'picklist';
customField.type_x = 'Picklist';

// Define the Value Set and Value Set Definitions
MetadataService.ValueSet vs = new MetadataService.ValueSet();
MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition vd = new MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition();

// Define the picklist values
List<MetadataService.CustomValue> customValues = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();
MetadataService.CustomValue cv1 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
cv1.label = 'One';
cv1.fullName = 'One';
cv1.isActive = true;
cv1.default_x = false;
customValues.add(cv1);
MetadataService.CustomValue cv2 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
cv2.label = 'Two';
cv2.fullName = 'Two';
cv2.isActive = true;
cv2.default_x = true;
customValues.add(cv2);


vd.value = customValues;
vd.sorted = true;

vs.valueSetDefinition = vd;

// Use valueSet instead of Picklist
customField.valueSet  = vs;

List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
    service.createMetadata(
        new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
```

I also had to make one more change to the `MetadataService.cls` as [per this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239936/metadata-api-error-while-reading-picklist-web-service-callout-failed-unable-to) which is to replace

```
public virtual class CustomValue extends Metadata {
    public String color;
    public Boolean default_x;
    public String description;
    public Boolean isActive;
    public String label;
}
```

with

```
public virtual class CustomValue extends Metadata {
    public String type = 'CustomValue';
    public String fullName;
    private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
    public String color;
    public Boolean default_x;
    public String description;
    public Boolean isActive;
    public String label;
    private String[] color_type_info = new String[]{'color',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] default_x_type_info = new String[]{'default',SOAP_M_URI,null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] description_type_info = new String[]{'description',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] isActive_type_info = new String[]{'isActive',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] label_type_info = new String[]{'label',SOAP_M_URI,null,'0','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{SOAP_M_URI,'true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fullName','color','default_x','description','isActive','label'};
}
```