# How to populate Dependent PickList value in Apex Class/ Trigger

Tags: apex

I need to populate some picklist value on an `Opportunity` Trigger.

There are two pickList : '`PickList1`' and '`PickList2`' . Both of them are on same `Opportunity` Object, 2nd one  is the dependent on the earlier.

When I populate PickList1 on the trigger, how can I get the relevent value of '`PickList2`' ?

I know by using If statement and by using hard code Picklist value we can implement our logic. But thing is we don't want to hard code the value of Picklist.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using out of box dependent pick lists? Are these 2 picklists on 2 diff objects, if they are then taking custom setting option would help you keep the picklist mapping more under control than hardcoding values

Comment: @rao : No, they are 2 fields of Same Object.

Comment: why are you using triggers then, can you not go dependent picklist route?

Comment: A quick search reveals the answer:

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex