# Exporting Picklist Values and the combinations

Tags: apex, picklist, dependent-picklist

We have 3 different picklist fields in our Case object

**Queue/Type/Area**

- Queue controls Type values.
- Type controls Area values.

I would like to know whether there is a way to export picklist values in the following format from the application depending upon the controlling-dependent field mappings.

For Example

Queue values are : {Q1,Q2,Q3}

Type values are  : {T1,T2,T3}

Area values are  : {A1,A2,A3}

Contolling-dependent mappings are as follows

### Queue-Type mapping

{Q1-T1}

{Q2-T2}

{Q3-T3}

### Type-Area Mapping

{T1-A1}

{T2-A2}

{T3-A3}

My desired output should be

{Q1-T1-A1}

{Q2-T2-A2}

{Q3-T3-A3}

I am okay if the solution is obtainable via code also.

Can someone throw me some pointers as to how can I achieve that ?

Comment: looks like there is a way to identify the dependent picklist values. would need some work though : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex