# Dynamic Apex for display dependent picklist in vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have two picklist fields Category__c and SubCust__c(dependent on Category__c field). How to display this field values in vf page as multiselect from a Apex Class.

Currently both multiselect are published as static using dynamic apex.

Need help how to display as dependent.

[image]

```
public List<SelectOption> getDept()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult departfield =  Activity_Tracker__c.Category__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklist = departfield.getPicklistValues();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : picklist){      
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }    
        return options;
    }



public List<SelectOption> getDept()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult departfield =  Activity_Tracker__c.SubCust__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklist = departfield.getPicklistValues();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : picklist){      
        options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }    
        return options;
    }
```

Regards

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: What kind of multiselect you want? Can you share some screenshot or mockup of what you want to implement?

Comment: Hi Patlatus.. I have updated my question..

Comment: Is your screenshot about what you would like to see or what do you currently see?

Comment: Currently i am displaying them individually using dynamic apex, but i want Sub customer should get populated according value selected in Category..

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are asking about, it is called as dependent\controlling picklist fields, you need to specify on field definition level that second picklist is dependent and select values available for each values of controlling field.

So you may use either apex:inputField or apex:selectList.
If you want to allow users to select several values at a time you may set multiselect="true"

---

UPD.

You have the same name for two methods, you need have different method names.
You may use something like this

```
<apex:actionRegion >
    <apex:selectList value="{!controllingField}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!contFieldOptions}"/>
        <apex:actionsupport event="onchange"  rerender="depFieldParent" />
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:actionRegion>
<apex:outputPanel id="depFieldParent">
    <apex:selectList value="{!dependentField}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!depFieldOptions}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

In the controller you may add more logic like this

```
public List<SelectOption> getDepFieldOptions() {
   List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult departfield =  Activity_Tracker__c.SubCust__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklist = departfield.getPicklistValues();
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : picklist){
        if ( controllingField != null ) { // you may want to add more logic here
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }
    }    
    return options;
}
```

---

UPD:
You may still use your unaltered version of getDept() method as getContFieldOptions to retrieve option for controller field:

```
public List<SelectOption> getContFieldOptions() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult departfield =  Activity_Tracker__c.Category__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> picklist = departfield.getPicklistValues();
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : picklist){      
    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
    }    
    return options;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code that i am using to display the values. But i need a logic where i can make it dependent..

Comment: Hi Patlatus.. I am bit consfused as the above method will only display the picklist values of SubCust__c. Can u please help me out in this..

Comment: Are you asking about  getDept() \ getContFieldOptions() to retrieve option for controller field? You may still use your unaltered version of your method, I didn't include it before since I didn't have to make any changes inside of it. Now I have updated my answer to include it as well.

Answer (score 0):

GetPicklistValues() doesn't return dependent picklist values; it returns all the values under that picklist. Your current approach will not work.

One solution for this is via API which is described in detail here: [Get lists of dependent picklist options in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex)

Another Option:
I had a similar issue wherein I needed to get picklist values dependent on record types. I used the solution described here:http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2012/01/record-type-picklist-values.html
See if you can modify this to work for dependent picklists.