# See all picklist values for a dependent field

Tags: soql, community, workbench

I have several fields among them two fields are 1.**Master** and 2.**Child** and i have created dependency between them.I want to know that how can I get(preferably using Wokbench) all available values of **Child** corresponding of a **Master** record.
I am new in Salesforce. It will be great if the solution is easy to implement.

Comment: Do you want to use in vf page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get lists of dependent picklist options in Apex](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex)

Answer (score 1):

There are very limited means to access this information. As per SF Documentation this information is available using APIs.

Anyways, there are several posts about this topic

[Get lists of dependent picklist options in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex)

http://titancronus.com/blog/2014/05/01/salesforce-acquiring-dependent-picklists-in-apex/

Additionally, I am curious to know what will be your next step after accessing this information in Workbench?

Comment: +1 for the links. Probably should be flagged as a dupe, though not sure if you have enough rep for that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this chrome extension to export the picklist matrix. This supports both classic and lightning. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-dependent-pick/fpieolagnlkejcpejlbjgbdpaglffacj

The csv file when opened in excel has first column as controlling field and second column as dependent field. you can then filter as required.