# Dynamic Picklist values based on RecordType selection in VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout, record-type

I have a requirement to show dynamic picklist values based on recordType. I did my research but looks like nothing native from Apex can handle this.

I went the route of calling Describelayout method via AjaxToolkit but always returns an empty array. Not sure if that's supported anymore?

[image: Workbench Describe]

Comment: That's the Developer Workbench, not the Ajax Toolkit.

Comment: With the use of Ajaxtoolkit also, I got the empty array. Instead of showing you too many logs, I am showing you from the workbench what I meant by empty array

Comment: What exactly do the page layouts have to do with picklist values?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I get the intersection of RecordType and Picklist values inside Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103837)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values using `describeLayout` method available in Ajax Toolkit. I tried with below code and I am able to get the picklist values based on the record type. There are two RecordTypes "Author" and "Publisher" and have different values in picklist Country__c. You can find the result in the screenshot.

```
var result =  sforce.connection.describeLayout('sarojkbera__Book__c');
console.log(result);
```

Browser console screenshot:

[image]