# how to get the picklist values by record type in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, record-type

My requirement is when i get the picklist values from account, it is showing all pick list values irrespective of record type?how to do this?

```
public List<selectOption> getPickValues(Sobject object_name, String field_name, String first_val) {
  List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); //new list for holding all of the picklist options
  //if (first_val != null) { //if there is a first value being provided
     options.add(new selectOption('','--None--')); //add the first option
  //}

  Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = object_name.getSObjectType(); //grab the sobject that was passed
  Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe(); //describe the sobject
  Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = sobject_describe.fields.getMap(); //get a map of fields for the passed sobject
  List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get(field_name).getDescribe().getPickListValues(); //grab the list of picklist values for the passed field on the sobject
  for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) { //for all values in the picklist list
        options.add(new selectOption(a.getValue(), a.getLabel())); //add the value and label to our final list
  } 
  return options; //return the List
}
//Sobject Account;
//Sobject Contact;
Account a=new Account(RecordTypeId='0120n0000004VDs');
Contact c=new Contact();
public List<SelectOption> getAccountType(){
    return getPickValues(a, 'Type', NULL); 
}
public List<SelectOption> getAccountCountry(){
    return getPickValues(a, 'Country__c', NULL); 
}
public List<SelectOption> getContactType(){
    return getPickValues(c, 'Type__c', NULL); 
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can't you use apex:inputField for picklists? It respects the record type.

Comment: I need to show drop down values based on the record type by using select options

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103837/how-do-i-get-the-intersection-of-recordtype-and-picklist-values-inside-apex

Answer (score 3):

I can't figure out a way to do this in simple Apex, but it looks like you can do it via the metadata API (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gNpLAAU) and the open source FinancialForce library (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

Answer (score 0):

Note : When adding new record types it’s possible to include a picklist field on the page layout but it fails to make any of the picklist values available for use. The result is a field you have full access to but no way of seeing or selecting a picklist value recently added but not added in available options for picklist. Therefore make sure to mark it in the available list.

Answer (score -2):

Here are the steps you need to follow!

Click: Setup > Create> Objects> Section_2_Balance_Sheet_c> Record Types > then click on each of the record types you need to add the picklist value to.
On the record type detail page you will find a section called Picklists Available for Editing. From that list locate your picklist field and click Edit.
Add the values you need to the right column.
Click Save.