# System.UserInfo.getSessionId() and metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, session, session-id

I am trying to do an API within my Salesforce to get the describe metadata, from [winter 19 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_streamline_api_calls.htm) and [this idea that was marked as already delivered (Allow Apex to call Salesforce REST and SOAP API's without a Remote Site Setting)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l7iEAAQ), I understood that I dont required to do the API to retrieve the session ID and I can use System.UserInfo.getSessionId(), also I will not need to set up the remote site.

However, this still not the case I still have to set up remote site setting and if I try using System.UserInfo.getSessionId(), I get the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID</faultcode>
            <faultstring>INVALID_SESSION_ID: This session is not valid for use with the API</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is there something else that I need to add to the System.UserInfo.getSessionId() to avoid having to ask an already signed user for their username, password and security token? in order to use this when calling making a call to the metadata endpoint? (https://xxxxx--sandbox.cs6.my.salesforce.com/**services/Soap/m**/46.0/00DN0......)

Comment: In what context is your code running? What is the API version? What Describe information are you trying to obtain from the Metadata API rather than the Apex Describe API?

Comment: @DavidReed: API: 46; running from aura component (there is an actual session ID as I can print it in console.log); the org metadata: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:met="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"><soapenv:Header><met:CallOptions><met:client>?</met:client></met:CallOptions><met:SessionHeader><met:sessionId>.......</met:sessionId></met:SessionHeader></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><met:describeMetadata><met:asOfVersion>46</met:asOfVersion></met:describeMetadata></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightning Components' Apex controllers [do not receive an API-enabled session](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm):

> By security policy, sessions created by Lightning components aren’t enabled for API access. This prevents even your Apex code from making API calls to Salesforce. Using a named credential for specific API calls allows you to carefully and selectively bypass this security restriction.
>
> The restrictions on API-enabled sessions aren’t accidental. Carefully review any code that uses a named credential to ensure you’re not creating a vulnerability.

You *do* get a session Id, it's just not API-enabled.
The recommended route, as alluded to above, is to use a Named Credential.