# Getting Null Picklist Values From SOQL

Tags: apex, visualforce

I Have a  custom picklist field in a case object.I am trying to fetch the picklist values into the visual force page.while Quering the picklist field in apex i am note getting all the values existing in picklist and also repetetion of values and null values.

```
options1 = new List<SelectOption>();        
List<case> subcatdet = [SELECT  ID,Sub_Category__c FROM case ];                                             
system.debug('subcatdet ..'+subcatdet );
for(case cs : subcatdet){
    options1.add(new SelectOption(cs.ID, cs.Sub_Category__c));             
}       
return options1;
```

Comment: You would not get all the values of picklist while putting a SOQL query. It simply returns value of particular record.

Comment: I saw that you mentioned dependent picklists in the comment to Adrian; in that case, you should simply use `apex:inputField` and bind directly to the field. Visualforce automatically supports dependent picklists.

Comment: See the [Winter '11](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/168/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_winter11_release_notes.pdf) release notes, page 124.

Comment: That is fine.Is there any possible way to handle with apex instead of that

Answer (score 5):

You should get metadata here, not data. Use describes to get the possible values:

```
subCategories = List<SelectOption>();
DescribeFieldResult describe = Case.Sub_Category__c.getDescribe();
for (PicklistEntry entry : describe.getPicklistValues())
{
    subCategories.add(new SelectOption(entry.getValue(), entry.getLabel());
}
return subCategories;
```

---

Note that you don't really need to put this information in `Apex`, as the `<apex:inputField>` tag will handle this functionality for you.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Case.ControllingPicklist}" />
<apex:inputField value="{!Case.DependentPicklist}" />
```

Comment: i have tried by getting metadata but i am not getting the dependency values in another picklist by using that

Comment: If you want dependency values that's a whole different ball of wax, but still should be accessed via metadata. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex