# Create JSON from Picklist Entries with both Controller and Dependent Picklist

Tags: apex, jquery, picklist, json

Am having JQuery auto complete search box in visualforce page. Currently the input for this search box is(ajax data) JSON. Which is a static resource file. But If client add one more option in the picklist field then they can't able find that option in the auto complete search box. So, I want to make it as dynamic. So decided to get the values in apex and form a JSON and pass the JSON data from apex to ajax call.

Picklist Field Names

1. Technology - Controlling picklist
2. Sub Technology - Dependent Picklist

Currently my static resource JSON file is looking like this(sample),

```
[  
   {  
      "techarea":"Dotnet",
      "subtecharea":"Csharp",
      "keywords":"",
      "label":"Dotnet => Csharp => "
   },
   {  
      "techarea":"Dotnet",
      "subtecharea":"ASP",
      "keywords":"",
      "label":"Dotnet => ASP => "
   },
   {  
      "techarea":"JAVA",
      "subtecharea":"JSP",
      "keywords":"",
      "label":"JAVA => JSP => "
   }
]
```

Am trying with Schema Picklist Entries method but can't able to build with controller and dependent format.
Really appreciable if anyone help me to achieve this.

Updated:

Sample Class Am trying to build

```
public class CreateJSONFromPicklists {

public void createFromCaseTATSAPicklists(){
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult TAfieldResult = Case.Technology_Area__c.getDescribe();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult TSAfieldResult = Case.Sub_Technology_Area__c.getDescribe();

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> TAple = TSAfieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> TSAple = TSAfieldResult.getPicklistValues();

    Transient String buildJSON = '';
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry TAf : TAple)
    {
        for(Schema.PicklistEntry TSAf: TSAple){
            // options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
            buildJSON += '{"techarea":'+ TAf.getValue()+',"subtecharea":'+TSAf.getValue()+',"keywords":"","label":"'+TAf.getValue()+' => '+TSAf.getValue()+' => "},';
        }

    }
    system.debug('@@@ BuildJSON @@@ '+buildJSON);
    //return options;
}
```

}

But apex heap size issue is throwing here. Also doubt on controlling dependent values format.

Comment: Can you check this question -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex

Comment: Awesome!. works great. I did some modifications to get the JSON data. Am pasting the whole class below for someone's reference.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for this great gist post https://gist.github.com/boxfoot/4166342

So here is my whole class to build fieldDenpendency JSON data

```
public class CreateJSONFromPicklists {
public static string getDependentOptionsImpl(Schema.SObjectField theField, Schema.SObjectField ctrlField) {
        // validFor property cannot be accessed via a method or a property,
        // so we need to serialize the PicklistEntry object and then deserialize into a wrapper.
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> contrEntries = ctrlField.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
        List<PicklistEntryWrapper> depEntries = CreateJSONFromPicklists.wrapPicklistEntries(theField.getDescribe().getPicklistValues());

        // Set up the return container - Map<ControllingValue, List<DependentValues>>
        Map<String, List<String>> objResults = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> controllingValues = new List<String>();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry ple : contrEntries) {
            String label = ple.getLabel();
            objResults.put(label, new List<String>());
            controllingValues.add(label);
        }

        for (PicklistEntryWrapper plew : depEntries) {
            String label = plew.label;
            String validForBits = base64ToBits(plew.validFor);
            for (Integer i = 0; i < validForBits.length(); i++) {
                // For each bit, in order: if it's a 1, add this label to the dependent list for the corresponding controlling value
                String bit = validForBits.mid(i, 1);
                if (bit == '1') {
                    objResults.get(controllingValues.get(i)).add(label);
                }
            }
        }
        string fieldDependencies = '';
        for(string controllervalue : objResults.keySet()){
            if(objResults.get(controllervalue) != null){
                List<String> dependencies = objResults.get(controllervalue);
                for(string dependentValue : dependencies){
                    fieldDependencies+= '{"techarea":"'+controllervalue+'","subtecharea":"'+dependentValue+'","keywords":"","label":"'+controllervalue+' => '+dependentValue+' => "},';
                }

            }
        }
        system.debug('@@@ fieldDependencies @@@ '+fieldDependencies);
        return fieldDependencies;
    }

    // Convert decimal to binary representation (alas, Apex has no native method :-(
    //    eg. 4 => '100', 19 => '10011', etc.
    // Method: Divide by 2 repeatedly until 0. At each step note the remainder (0 or 1).
    // These, in reverse order, are the binary.
    public static String decimalToBinary(Integer val) {
        String bits = '';
        while (val > 0) {
            Integer remainder = Math.mod(val, 2);
            val = Integer.valueOf(Math.floor(val / 2));
            bits = String.valueOf(remainder) + bits;
        }
        return bits;
    }

    // Convert a base64 token into a binary/bits representation
    // e.g. 'gAAA' => '100000000000000000000'
    public static String base64ToBits(String validFor) {
        if (String.isEmpty(validFor)) return '';

        String validForBits = '';

        for (Integer i = 0; i < validFor.length(); i++) {
            String thisChar = validFor.mid(i, 1);
            Integer val = base64Chars.indexOf(thisChar);
            String bits = decimalToBinary(val).leftPad(6, '0');
            validForBits += bits;
        }

        return validForBits;
    }


    private static final String base64Chars = '' +
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' +
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' +
        '0123456789+/';


    private static List<PicklistEntryWrapper> wrapPicklistEntries(List<Schema.PicklistEntry> PLEs) {
        return (List<PicklistEntryWrapper>)
            JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(PLEs), List<PicklistEntryWrapper>.class);
    }

    public class PicklistEntryWrapper {
        public String active {get; set;}
        public String defaultValue {get; set;}
        public String label {get; set;}
        public String value {get; set;}
        public String validFor {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Invoking like this,

CreateJSONFromPicklists.getDependentOptionsImpl(Case.Sub_Technology_Area__c, Case.Technology_Area__c);