# How to dynamically find restricted picklist values in apex?

Tags: apex, opportunity, picklist, profile

My team is using the Opportunities object to build an intake system for a number of different internal groups. To identify the page layout we give each group a "delivery group" custom field that is automatically assigned by their profile (which is set to their group).

Example: Group A is Profile A -> Delivery_Owner__c = Group A

From there, the page layouts limit some picklists, such as stage. This is because each group's intakes have different stages, with some overlaps. What I need to do is obtain the picklist for each group (and only that group) so I can limit the displayed opportunities in a VF page.

EX: Group A has stages 1, 2, 3 while B has 4, 5, 6.

How do I do this in an apex controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Get lists of dependent picklist options in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/4462/2995)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SFSE. I recommend you check the [ask] page. Normally, people here will not write code for you. In fact, many of us get paid to do that. However, if you have written something, we will be more than happy to help you complete it and/or diagnose the problems you're having. Again, welcome!