# How do I get Country State Picklist Values in a lightning component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, country-and-state

We have State and Country Picklist enabled in the org. I cannot find a way to find out the list of states based on the selected country. I need this in the lightning component.

I've used DescribeFieldResult in Apex to get the country and return it to the component in init. It is fine. But I cannot find any way to filter the States based on CountryCode.

Is there any direct way to do this? Or should I be implementing via adding those into Custom Settings.

```
<aura:attribute name="dynamicCountry" type="Object[]"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="dynamicState" type="Object[]"></aura:attribute>



<lightning:inputAddress
        aura:id="myaddress"
        addressLabel="Address"
        streetLabel="Street"
        cityLabel="City"
        countryLabel="Country"
        provinceLabel="Province/State"
    postalCodeLabel="PostalCode"
        street="1 Market St."
        city="San Francisco"
        country="US"
        countryOptions="{! v.dynamicCountry }"
        provinceOptions="{! v.dynamicState }"
        postalCode="94105"
        required="true"
    />
```

I get the countryoptions and provinceoptions populated from apex in init of lightning component. Both of them would get populated. The issue is filtering out the state based on country code in apex (and it always returns me the full list). I still need to write a change event on the inputAddress field to fire when country is changed (and call the function to populate the state). But I need to figure it out at Apex level how to achieve this.

Note: I also need to make this work with multiple languages. Hence I'm choosing to get it from the Country State picklist values.

Comment: How are you implementing your lightning component? As if you are using inputfield or select components? Providing some code here will help.

Comment: @JayantDas - Thanks for checking. I added more details in the question. Hoping to get some inputs / tips

Comment: Check this link, specially read all the comments for the accepted answer. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4462/get-lists-of-dependent-picklist-options-in-apex?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa It seems possible.

Comment: Please check this link also https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/dependent-picklists-in-salesforce-without-metadata-api-or-visualforce/

Answer (score 1):

---

### **EDIT**

I later found this topic being discussed in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214872/how-to-present-state-and-country-picklists-with-dependency-logic-in-a-lightning). So definitely there's no way to use the standard `lighting:inputAddress` for this purpose.

I additionally tried using the `lightning:inputField` on Country/State, and that did not work either. So it looks like you may need to actually write some custom logic to maintain the dependency in the backend and handle *onchange* event with every country selection to populate the state values. You can find more details on this approach on the post referred above.

---

Looking at the documentation, it seems that while using the standard `lightning:inputAddress`, you may not be able to define the dependency between country and state out of the box. The values in here are just standard array values and they really don't have any dependency defined between them. You can possibly capture the `onchange` or `onblur` events and manipulate the values.

But I wouldn't recommend to go that route as it would require much more event handling and that you will always need to maintain and refer to a matrix defined for country/state mapping. As far as your apex scenario is considered, if you can address the dependency by handling the events, you will get the selected value without considering for anything in apex.

In your scenario I would rather recommend to use `lightning:inputField` which can render values based on the field type and also renders any dependency within picklist. The below excerpt is from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputField.htm):

> Dependent picklists must be defined in your org before you can use them with lightning:inputField. Both controlling and dependent fields must be included in your component.

**Note:** *I haven't really used `lightning:inputField` with Country/State picklist, but assume the behavior is similar as for any other dependent picklist.*

In all other cases, you will need to resort to some customization.