# Why does the DependentPicklists class returns empty Map when trying to output Country and State picklist?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, dependent-picklist, country-and-state

We are implementing the DependentPicklists class found in [another answer on this sit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214872/how-to-present-state-and-country-picklists-with-dependency-logic-in-a-lightning)e. Our org has State and Country picklists enabled, so we are trying to get this to work using the `Contact.MailingCountry` and `Contact.MailingState` fields.

Once I get this to work, I plan to return the result via `@AuraEnabled` method.

Here's how I'm mocking it up:

```
String stateString = 'Contact.MailingState';

List<String> splitStateString = stateString.split('\\.');

Schema.SobjectField stateField = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(splitStateString[0]).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(splitStateString[1]);

System.debug('State Field: ' + stateField);

String countryString = 'Contact.MailingCountry';

List<String> splitCountryString = countryString.split('\\.');

Schema.SobjectField countryField = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(splitCountryString[0]).getDescribe().fields.getMap().get(splitCountryString[1]);

System.debug('Country Field: ' + countryField);

DependentPicklists dp = new DependentPicklists();

Map<String, List<String>> result =  dp.controllingToDependentValues(countryField, stateField);

System.debug(result.size());
System.debug(result.keySet().size());
System.debug(result);
```

The result is as follows:

```
12:00:02.44 (156941497)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|State Field: MailingState
12:00:02.44 (166692772)|USER_DEBUG|[15]|DEBUG|Country Field: MailingCountry
12:00:02.44 (170849255)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|0
12:00:02.44 (170924837)|USER_DEBUG|[22]|DEBUG|0
12:00:02.44 (170952466)|USER_DEBUG|[23]|DEBUG|{}
```

What am I missing that is keeping me from getting results?

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is about implementing that answer/solution.

Comment: retracted close vote.. +1

Comment: Probably worth having a look into Salesforce UI API.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values.htm?search_text=picklist

Answer (score 0):

*This probably does not help [@Swisher Sweet](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12290/), who I am sure has gotten this working in the past year and a half; but for future seekers (like myself)....*

---

#### Answer

**You have to use** `Contact.MailingCountryCode` **and** `Contact.MailingStateCode`.

(Or other objects and fields, like:

`Account.BillingCountryCode` and `Account.BillingStateCode`.

*It is the appended* `Code` *that is important*.)

---

#### References

1. I haven't yet found an explicit statement in Salesforce documentation about these fields used in this context.  (I also haven't overturned every stone.)  The best I have found referencing using these fields at all is here:

   SALESFORCE HELP > DOCS > SET UP AND MAINTAIN YOUR SALESFORCE ORGANIZATION > Provide Maps and Location Services > Let Users Select State and Country from Picklists

   Under *State and Country Picklist Limitations*:

   > You can access your records’ state and country code values by using
   > the `StateCode` and `CountryCode` fields in Workbench or the Data Loader.
2. It is stated/included/mentioned-in-passing in questions, answers and comments all over this forum.  Here are a few:

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/214910/81648
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/263760/81648

  and an especially helpful answer just to keep in the back of your mind:
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/288615/81648