# How do I retrieve Country and State Picklist Values (AddressSettings) via API?

Tags: api, rest, metadata, dependent-picklist, country-and-state

How do I get a dependent list of States by Country from Salesforce via API?

Our Use Case is: We need dependent Picklists on an integrated 3rd party web platform we intend to pass the returned Countries and STate into a JS array so that we can make the Country field control the State field .
We have States&Countries enabled in settings.

We prefer REST.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the values in a convenient REST resource by itself, but if you describe the object, you'll get the dependencies:

```
/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/describe
```

This gives back a JSON that includes all fields, record type information, etc. If you look at the `fields` object, you'll find `BillingStateCode`, which contains `picklistValues`, which is a list that includes the `value`, `label`, and the `validFor` bitmap.

You'll want to read [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4876) for how to decode validFor. Basically, you read the bits from left to right; if it's a 1 bit, then the picklist value in the controlling field is valid, otherwise not.

Comment: Great Answers, this and the other question, thanks again.
My integrator doesn't want to consume the describe and do the translation, so I will build a Web Service with it in a more usable array format, and they can consume that.